# How to timeout Mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a service that connects two different mongo clusters.

```
 const persons1 = this.Person1
  .find(
    { }
  )
  .lean();

 const persons2 = this.Person2
  .find(
    { }
  )
  .lean();
```

I can merge this requests by:

```
 const allPersons = await Promise.all([persons1, persons2]);
 return allPersons[0].concat(allPersons[1]);
```

This works well when two connections are stable. However, I want to set some timeout for each query, at least serve one of them in case any server is not responding. However, though I close one of the mongo servers my query still waits, therefore I'm unable to catch the error (by default I want to return any empty array). Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-maxTimeMS

> Sets the maxTimeMS option. This will tell the MongoDB server to abort if the query or write op has been running for more than ms milliseconds.

> Calling query.maxTimeMS(v) is equivalent to query.setOption({ maxTimeMS: v })

https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/

```
const persons1 = this.Person1
  .find({ })
  .maxTimeMS(100) // set max execution time here
  .lean();

const persons2 = this.Person2
  .find({ })
  .maxTimeMS(100) // set max execution time here
  .lean();
```

---

```
const allPersons = await Promise.all([persons1, persons2]);
const results = allPersons.filter(r => !(r instanceof Error)); // filter the records which are executed without any errors
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This works well if the server cannot process the request within the specified time, but we have to catch errors `Promise.all([persons1, persons2].map(p => p.catch(() => []))` also. However, I want to be able to timeout the query if the server is down. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @esilik to get the records or error details loop over `allPersons` array.  What do you mean by the server is down? Does it mean database is down ?

Comment: Yes @Tushar Gupta - curioustushar

Comment: @esilik you can add check if db got disconnected `mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function(){});` Read for more details https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#error-handling https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection-events